# Is it possible to over-ride underlying filesystem using docker container?

Tags: docker, bazel, lustre

I want to use bazel to build tensorflow on CentOS 6.6 cluster which uses Lustre filesystem. This filesystem doesn't support locking. [Refer this issue on github](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2647).

I have read that docker can provide virtualisation. Will it be possible for me to use different filesystem to use bazel inside docker?

Comment: Even with Docker you would still need access to a local filesystem with appropriate locking semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This (Lustre) filesystem doesn't support locking

Lustre *does* support file locking, even between clients, it just doesn't enable this by default because of overhead.  If your application is running on only a single node, you can mount the Lustre client using the `-o localflock` mount option, which enables flock but it is not coherent across client nodes.  This is the fastest if you only need flock for a single-node application.

If you need flock to be coherent between an application running on multiple client nodes at the same time, mount all of the involved clients with the `-o flock` mount option.